# Video capture dialog keeps popping up with embedded PC webcam delphi app

Tags: delphi, api, webcam, video-capture, windows-embedded

I have a delphi app that takes snapshots from a webcam at 1 sec intervals.  On the development PC it goes fine, but on the target platform (Atom-based tablet PC running embedded Windows 7 with a different camera) it is extremely flaky.  After a reboot and the first time the app is run, it normally manages to initialise the webcam OK and get regular frames from it, but the next time the app is run, it fails to locate the webcam driver, and also pops up a dialog asking me to specify the video source, presumably because it can't find one..

My question:  I'm sure this is related to video capture API calls not being in the right order or something, but is there a tool (like wireshark) that will enable me to sniff the API calls, so I can compare what is happening on the embedded Windows 7 system to the XP development system that works?

I am using the following calls/messages:

Initialisation:

```
capCreateCaptureWindow
WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT
WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW (false)
WM_CAP_SET_VIDEOFORMAT (as camera after boot is in format I can't handle)
WM_CAP_GET_VIDEOFORMAT
```

On 1 sec timer:

```
WM_CAP_SET_CALLBACK_FRAME
WM_CAP_GRAB_FRAME_NOSTOP
```

On callback:

```
WM_CAP_SET_CALLBACK_FRAME (nil)
```

On finish:

```
WM_CAP_ABORT
WM_CAP_STOP
WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT
```

Comment: This question is unclear. Are you asking how to make the driver-selection more reliable, or are you asking how to monitor API calls? Those are two completely separate issues, and if you want to ask about both, then you should make multiple posts. And which of those questions does the accepted answer resolve?

Comment: Marco's suggestion to introduce a delay (or actually, a delay and retries) has made driver selection more reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is a lot easier: Did you make absolutely sure you have the same driver?

It might also be that the sequence of detect - start acquisition is too fast for this slow system. See if introducing a few secs sleep inbetween helps

Comment: Development system:  Win XP SP3. Logitech camera. Device manager lists 22 MS and logitech drivers.  Embedded system:  Intel Atom Win 7 Embedded. D-Max camera uses Syntek controller. Device manager lists one driver usbvideo.sys

Comment: That's not an answer :-) Are they the same, with the same vendor, date etc? Different drivers might behave different, specially when comparing a generic MS driver vs a logitech device specific one.

Comment: It was supposed to be an answer.  Sorry, my point was that the two systems are completely different, but the embedded driver is the MS one, which we would hope to be stable.

Comment: Thanks Marco.  It seems that it's a known issue with Windows 7.  Entering a loop with a sleep (1000) between each attempt opens it after the 2nd or third attempt.  Now I just have to figure out how to close the "Video Source" dialog (trying "FindWindow" but no luck yet - see my question on this if you have any ideas).